# Where can I see ATLTRACE output?

Tags: c++, com, atl

I'm maintaining a C++ COM project. There are some trace lines like ATLTRACE(message);
I searched ATLTRACE. MSDN told Visual C++ output window will display it. However, the product is a release one. The customer won't have the source nor to debug it in VS. So is there any other convenient way to see it? Will Windows Event viewer catch that? Or I have to change the code?  Win7, VS2013

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ATLTRACE only uses only the debug output and it works only in the Debug version!

So you may give the enduser a debug version for testing purpose, and use DebugView from Sysinternals. But this may be complicated because you also have to over the debug runtimes that are not redistributable.

But you can easily write your own MY_TRACE macro that has the same functionality.

```
#define MY_TRACE  GetMyTracer()   // returns object of CMyTracer
...

class CMyTracer
{
  ...
  // Helper operator to get the trace commands. They call the TraceV functions
  void operator()(PCSTR pszFormat, ...);
  void operator()(PCWSTR pszFormat, ...);

  // Worker functions that do the real job calling TraceV functions
  void Trace(PCSTR pszFormat, ...);
  void Trace(PCWSTR pszFormat, ...);

  // Allowed to be virtual to do some internal mystique stuff, like redirecting and this functions perform all output...
  virtual void TraceV(PCSTR pszFormat, va_list args);
  virtual void TraceV(PCWSTR pszFormat, va_list args);
  ...
```

Now you can use this instead of ATLTRACE

```
...
MYTRACE("Simple output\n");
MYTRACE("More complex output %d\n", 4711);
```

Note: It is not wise to replace all ATLTRACE macros with your own replacement. You may spread your trace output onto locations were it don't have impact un speed, but is worth the information.

Answer (score 1):

`ATLTRACE` is a macro that compiles to nothing in a release build.  You'll need to rebuild the project with the _DEBUG macro defined (see `<atltrace.h>`) to get those to display.  However, output generated by `ATLTRACE` is a debug output string, and will typically only display in the debugger's output window.

If there is important information you need, and if it is in code you control, you'll be better off changing the `ATLTRACE` macro usage to something else, to either log to the event log or a log file the customer can send to you.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by 1201ProgramAlarm, release builds of ATL projects have ATLTRACE macros evaluated to nothing and the binary has no real code generated for respective source code lines. That is, you cannot see the output without altering source code.

In order to not alter the project much, you can redefine the tracing macro itself and produce release build with tracing capabilities where output is routed as defined by you, for example to standard debug output using `OutputDebugString` API.

See:

- [How to enable the TRACE macro in Release mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25657721/868014)
- [AtlReleaseTrace](http://alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/Utilities/Miscellaneous/AtlReleaseTrace)